# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 find column words in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table looks like:

```
AV          AVE
AVENUE      AVE
AVEAPT      AVE
APT         #
```

First word to be found and replaced by second word.

I have to find these words in Address field in another table and replace all these?

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE a
SET Address = REPLACE(Address, r.Word, r.Replacement)
FROM AddressTable AS a
JOIN ReplaceTable AS r
ON a.Address LIKE '%' + r.Word + '%'
```

Comment: If there is a word within a string like "rte 20 General Delivery", which needs also to be replaced by "rte 20 Gen Del". will it capture in between words as well?

Comment: @rsDesigner - The % in the LIKE statement means "anything", so the query will look for Addresses with the Word at the beginning, middle or end.  It will do it for each Word.